# Make multiple turtles move all at the same time

Tags: parallel-processing, netlogo

**What is the idea of the program**: We have watchdogs, sheep, wolves. My sheep are in a ford, the wolves are coming from outside, when entering the ford, watchdogs start moving. Wolves eat sheep, sheep eat grass, watchdogs should scare wolves (not yet implemented).

**My problem**: All the turtles are moving one at a time.

**What I want**: I want them to move all at once for every tick.

**Code**:

```
    breed [sheeps sheep]
breed [wolves wolf]
breed [watchdogs watchdog]

turtles-own [attacked?]

globals [counter
  attack
  sheep-energy
  wolf-energy
  grass-counter
  lifespan
  age
  num-attacks
  death-countdown]

to set-variables-shapes
  set lifespan 365 * 10
    set-default-shape sheeps "sheep"
    set-default-shape watchdogs "dog"
    set-default-shape wolves "wolf"
     set sheep-energy 200
     set wolf-energy 400
     set death-countdown 60
end

to setup
  clear-all
 set-variables-shapes
 create-fold
 spawn-animals
  reset-ticks

end

to go

   ask turtles [
     move
   ]
    respawn-grass

  ask sheeps [
    if ( pcolor != green or pcolor != brown) [
      move-to one-of patches with [ pcolor = green or pcolor = brown] ;; If i change this with turn-around (procedure), all sheeps die at once.
    ]
    eat-grass
    reproduce
    sheep-status
    death
 show sheep-energy
  ]

  ask wolves [
    attack-sheep
    if (xcor < 5 and xcor > -14 and ycor < 15 and ycor > -5 ) [

      ask watchdogs [
    move
    if ( pcolor != green or pcolor != brown ) [
      move-to one-of patches with [ pcolor = green]
    ]
      ]
    ]
  ]

tick
end

to create-fold
  ask patches [
    if (pxcor < 6 and pxcor > -15 and pycor < 16 and pycor > -6)[
      set pcolor grey]
    if (pxcor < 5 and pxcor > -14 and pycor < 15 and pycor > -5) [
      set pcolor green]
   ]

end


to sheep-status
  if (pcolor = brown) [
    set sheep-energy sheep-energy - (life-from-food / 2)]
  if attacked?
  [set color red]

 end


to attack-sheep
    ask other sheeps in-radius (size)[
      set attacked? true
        set color red
    ]

end
to reproduce
  if (age = lifespan / 10) [
    hatch-sheeps 40 [
      hatch-options
      ]
  ]
end

to eat-grass
  if (pcolor = green)[
    set pcolor brown
    set sheep-energy sheep-energy + life-from-food
  ]
end

to respawn-grass
  ask patches [
  if pcolor = brown [
    ifelse grass-counter = 0 [
      set pcolor green
      set grass-counter grass-respawn-timer
    ]
    [ set grass-counter grass-counter - 1]
  ]
  ]
  end
to death
  sheep-death-timer
  if (sheep-energy <= 0)
  [die]
  ;;if (age >= lifespan) [die]
  sheep-explode

end

to sheep-death-timer
  if (attacked?)[
  set death-countdown death-countdown - 1

  if (death-countdown  <= 30)
  [set color black]
  if (death-countdown <= 0)
  [die]
  ]
end

to sheep-explode
  if (sheep-energy >= 10000)[
  hatch-sheeps 20 [
    hatch-options]
  die
  ]
end

to hatch-options
  set sheep-energy 200
      set age 1
      set attacked? false
  end

to move
  fd 1
  rt random 90
  lt random 90
end

to spawn-animals
   create-wolves number-of-wolves [
      set color red
      setxy 10 -10
      set size 1.3
      ask patch 10 -10[
        Set plabel "Wolves"]
  ]
  create-sheeps number-of-sheeps [
     if (pxcor < 5 and pxcor > -14 and pycor < 15 and pycor > -5 )[
        setxy -4.5 5]
     ask patch -4.5 15 [
       Set plabel "Sheeps"]
  set color white
  set attacked? false
   ]
 create-watchdogs number-of-dogs [
    if (pxcor < 5 and pxcor > -14 and pycor < 15 and pycor > -5 )[
    setxy  -4.5 5
    set size 1.3]
  set color blue
  ]
end
to turn-around
  fd -1
  rt 180
end
```

Comment: You should ask your question about premature sheep death separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as "at the same time" in NetLogo. NetLogo is single-threaded and doesn't support parallel processing.

If all the agents move during the same tick, you can think of that as "at the same time", since it all happened during the course of a tick.

But within a single tick, there is literally no way for agents to move other than one at a time.

Comment: Thank you! Managed to learn more about NetLogo, and I eventually understood that it is not possible. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
ask-concurrent sheeps [move ]
```

to make each sheep agent all move at the same time, but it shouldn't matter and they actually don't recommend you use it.

Comment: `ask-concurrent` doesn't do that. The agents still move one at a time. (Explaining what `ask-concurrent` actually does is quite difficult, which is part of why we never recommend it.)